# Is it possible to save a view as image?

Tags: views, media

I have a view with a table and charts and I need to save it as image. Is this possible?

It can be an export of the page itself as long as it exports only the contents of the view without menus and other page elements.

Comment: One way is to use something that can screen capture like PhantomJS or other similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7, there are a couple of views to pdf modules available.

- [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf)
- [Views Data Export PdF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_pdf)

Not sure about a Drupal 8 version.

An alternative would be to use CSS print media queries to hide what you don't want to see when you print the page.  This can be usefull across the site for printing pages if you set it up properly.  If you need specific page settings, the body tag probably has a unique view class.  If not, you can add one with a preprocess function.

If you truely need an image, then phantomjs or similar combined with the correct CSS is probably your best bet.  There are some screenshot modules but they tend to use services and are probably not that configurable.

Comment: Tried PhantomJS without success. There is a test page inside drupal but I don't get any image. Anyone uses this module? I don't know what to put in "Path to phantomJS". Tried everything but I still can't get any image.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197100/8507497

Comment: Ok, I managed to install the library correctly. It's in "sites/all/libraries/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs" In the configuration page inside drupal it also detects the version correctly. Problem now is that when I use the Phantom JS test, it says Please Wait forever and no screenshot is ever created. What am I missing now?

Comment: UPDATE: the image is in fact created but it takes ~5min. Maybe it's the normal time. Anyone knows?